# How to add Identity Authentication Cookie Timeout in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an existing production ASP.NET Core 1.1 project that I have upgraded to ASP.NET Core 2.

I set the ASP.NET Core identity authentication cookie like this in ASP.NET Core 1.1 to 2 hours

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "MyApp";
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
     })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext, Guid>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

However in ASP.NET 2.0 Core the Cookies property has been removed from the AddIdentity option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to tweak Identity cookies, they're no longer part of IdentityOptions.
You will have use `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` like this-

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
            options.CookieName = "MyApp";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
        });
        ....
    }
```

Note: `CookieName` property is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. The recommended alternative is `Cookie.Domain`.

Comment: How will it now the above timeout is linked to my identity cookie and not some other cookie like if I make use of session cookie?